# QUERY data based on multi criteria

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula

Here's an example:

**Sheet1:**

[image: 4]

**Sheet2:**

[image: 2]

How do I match the price from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1 based on 3 criteria: Customer Name and Quantity under items? I need to return the Price on Sheet 1 and if cell states 0, return 'No order'.

[Here's a link to a testing sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b10uVt1j5n7gWg-2vxqtwzY9tbSqM5TymNEVZI8Anbc/edit#gid=1043826729)

I've tried `QUERY` formula but it does not work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN($A$2:$A), 
 TEXT(QUERY(QUERY('Helper Column'!$A$2:$D, 
 "Select *", 0), 
 "Select Col4 where Col1='"&$A2&"' and Col3='"&$B$1&"'", 0),
 "$###.00"), ), "No order")
```

[image]